# How to create an searchable add-reference-button/action in admin-on-rest?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Consider a case where I have a functional JSON backend, and the admin-on-rest resources `company`, `user` and `company_user`.

The data is as follows

## company

- id
- name
- address
  ...etc.

## user

- id
- name
- phone
- address
  ...etc.

## company_user

- id
- company_id (references company)
- user_id (references user)
- position
  ...etc.

It is very easy to have a *separate* top-level resource view for the `company_user` resource type; but it should really be editable per user and per company, on preferably on a tab of the `user`, or the `company` resource views.

Thus comes the problem: how to create a tab for `user` resource, where I can list the current `company`-references (`company_user` rows), but in the same tab I need a sane way to do the following functionality:

1. search for all the companies that are not currently referred to by this user (of course there is an API call for that);
2. add a row to to the `company_user` collection and;
3. refresh the tab

Comment: I was going to ask the very same question. As far as I understand, it is possible only with writing some custom React and it is not provided by the aor framework.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle this kind of relations is to provide an extra field on your models that will serve as a representation of the relations.

For example, from a user we need to see his companies: expose a new field `user.company_ids`.
This field don't have to be in the database, your API or a proxy can list the related companies ID in this field, and for write requests use it to create, change or delete relations.

Once this field is implemented, admin-on-rest is very easy to configure.
I made a fully working snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/r04y8rn96p

First, write your top-level resources:

```
<Admin
    authClient={authClient}
    restClient={restClient}
    title="Example Admin"
    locale="en"
    messages={messages}
  >
    <Resource
      name="companies"
      list={CompanyList}
      create={CompanyCreate}
      edit={CompanyEdit}
      show={CompanyShow}
      remove={Delete}
      icon={CompanyIcon}
    />
    <Resource
      name="users"
      list={UserList}
      create={UserCreate}
      edit={UserEdit}
      remove={Delete}
      icon={UserIcon}
      show={UserShow}
    />
    <Resource
      name="company_user"
      icon={CompanyUserIcon}
      list={CompanyUserList}
      create={CompanyUserCreate}
      show={CompanyUserShow}
      remove={Delete}
    />
</Admin>
```

Then, you can use `ReferenceArrayInput` for the user model on the extra field just like a one-to-many relation.

```
export const UserEdit = ({ ...props }) => (
  <Edit title={<UserTitle />} {...props}>
    <TabbedForm>
      <FormTab label="User Infos">
        <TextInput source="name" />
        <DateInput source="published_at" defaultValue={() => new Date()} />
        <TextInput source="company_ids" />
      </FormTab>
      <FormTab label="Companies">
        <ReferenceArrayInput source="company_ids" reference="companies">
          <SelectArrayInput optionText="title" />
        </ReferenceArrayInput>
      </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

Since the idea is to mock the relations into an extra field, you can handle this field from your backend (the best choice) or the frontend via the `restClient`. Here is an dummy example for read-only relations:

```
// It's better to implement these rules on the backend
const improvedRestClient = (type, resource, params) => {
  return restClient(type, resource, params).then((response) => {
    // Inject company_ids into user
    if (type === 'GET_ONE' && resource === 'users') {
      return restClient('GET_LIST', 'company_user', defaultOptions).then(({ data: companyUsers }) => {
        const user = response.data;

        return {
          data: {
            ...user,
            company_ids: companyUsers
              .filter(item => item.user_id === user.id)
              .map(item => item.company_id),
          },
        }
      });
    }

    // Inject user_ids into company
    if (type === 'GET_ONE' && resource === 'companies') {
      return restClient('GET_LIST', 'company_user', defaultOptions).then(({ data: companyUsers }) => {
        const company = response.data;

        return {
          data: {
            ...company,
            user_ids: companyUsers
              .filter(item => item.company_id === company.id)
              .map(item => item.user_id),
          },
        }
      });
    }

    return response;
  });
};
```